# plot errorbars but bars for only selected x-values

Tags: python, matplotlib, errorbar

I am able to plot error bars. However, I have far more data for the graph and I want to plot the error bars for only particular x values.
This means I that my error bar data and my graph data have different sizes. How can I do this?

```py
figure_name = simulation_name+"_eta="+eta+"_arm_length="+arm_length+"_nint="+str(current_nint)
fig1, axs1 = plt.subplots(1)
ys=fitnessesPlot[:,0:2000:100]
ys=np.random.randn(20,2000)
errorbars=np.std(ys,0)
ymean=np.mean(ys,0)
xs=np.linspace(0,1999,20)
plt.errorbar(xs,ymean,errorbars)
plt.savefig(path+"FitVsGen_"+filename+".png")
plt.close()
```

Comment: Plot some of the data with error bars and the rest as a scatter or line plot.

Comment: Ok, but won't it then also plot the graph for the selected x-values with the error bars? So then two lines will be visible

Comment: It depends on how you do it. I (or others) can help you more if you share a [minimum working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @jared I have included my code now.

Comment: Without `ys`, we cannot run this code. Please read the link I shared on minimum working examples.

Comment: @jared I changed the code by letting ys be a random 2d array. Sorry I am late. I woke up a couple of hours ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you specify your error values as an **array** (instead of a scalar), you can then set the error value to `np.nan` at those positions where you don't want to show errorbars:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

```
x = np.arange(10.0)
y = np.sin(x)

# make array of errors
e = np.full_like(x, y.std())
# remove every other error value
e[range(0, len(x), 2)] = np.nan

plt.errorbar(x, y, e, fmt='-o', ecolor='C1')
```

[image]

Comment: That's a really nice tweak! Thanks!